# Angular extending controllers

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have two controllers in my angular - 'table' and 'studentTable'.

**The problem is the $scope in 'table' cannot read the data from $scope in 'studentTable'.**

```
 Suppose $scope.data2 will be equal to $scope.data by clicking the button but it does not work.
```

The reason why I have two controllers is I have so many tables, like 'teacherTable', 'classRoomTable',etc and they all use the functions of 'table'. It is kind of like extending the 'table'. Is there any way I can make it works or even better?

```
(function () {
"use strict";
angular.module("app", []).controller("table", ['$scope', function ($scope) {
        return $scope.displayData = function () {
            return $scope.data2=$scope.data;
        };
    }])
    .controller("studentTable", ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {
        return $scope.getData = function () {
            $http.post('/api/getUserByUserId/1', {}).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                return $scope.data = data;
            }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            });
        }, $scope.getData();


    }])
})
<div data-ng-app="app">
<div data-ng-controller="table">
<div data-ng-controller="studentTable">
    {{data}}
    {{data2}}
    <button ng-click="displayData()">click</button>
</div>
```

Comment: you should make a table 'service' and make both scopes use it

Comment: scope is inherited by the child controller so student table will still be able to access scope in 'table'. Services provide a two way communication platform - you should set up a table service for use by these controllers